# C# compiler asks me to make my function awaitable but it already is?

Tags: c#, async-await

this line

```
 success = await _myHid.SendOutputReportViaInterruptTransfer(_deviceData, _hidHandle, outputReportBuffer);
```

gives me this error Error

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.  S:\blissbox\SOURCE_FILES\Bliss-Box_api\managed dx attempt\BBAPI.cs  40

here is my method.

```
internal async Task<Boolean> SendOutputReportViaInterruptTransfer
            (FileStream fileStreamDeviceData, SafeFileHandle hidHandle, Byte[] outputReportBuffer)
        {
            try
            {
                var success = false;

                    // Begin writing the Output report. 

                    Task t = fileStreamDeviceData.WriteAsync(outputReportBuffer, 0, outputReportBuffer.Length);

                    await t;

                    // Gets to here only if the write operation completed before a timeout.

                    Debug.Print("Asynchronous write completed");

                    // The operation has one of these completion states:

                    switch (t.Status)
                    {
                        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                            success = true;
                            Debug.Print("Output report written to device");
                            break;
                        case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                            Debug.Print("Task canceled");
                            break;
                        case TaskStatus.Faulted:
                            Debug.Print("Unhandled exception");
                            break;
                    }

                return success;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayException(ModuleName, ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The compiler is asking you to make the method from which you are calling `SendOutputReportViaInterruptTransfer` `async` as well.

Comment: When you introduce `async` into your project, you need to make the `async`'s go all the way up.  In other words, short of encapsulating the call in a task like `Task.Run(async() => { ... });` you need to make all the calling functions `async`, and all those calling functions' calling functions `async`, all the way up the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the location of the function which is called. It means where you called the following code is not an async function:

```
success = await _myHid.SendOutputReportViaInterruptTransfer(_deviceData, _hidHandle, outputReportBuffer);
```

One solution can be call this async function like the following:

```
var task = TaskEx.RunEx(async () => 
{
   await _myHid.SendOutputReportViaInterruptTransfer(_deviceData, _hidHandle, outputReportBuffer);
});
var result = task.WaitAndUnwrapException();
```

Comment: Wow I would have never got that form all the threads on S.O. I read on this, thx guys.